# VBA loop selection.find

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to loop or find multiple value in another sheets. My code doesn't work even after I `do..loop` the code.

```
For i = 1 To lastrowBAU

        Worksheets(fname).Range("A1:A" & lastrowsheet).Select
        
        Do Until Cell Is Nothing
         Set Cell = Selection.find(What:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BAU").Range("A" & i).Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False)
            
                 If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
        
                    Cell.Activate
                    ActiveCell.Copy
                    ActiveCell.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
                    
                             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                             
                    Selection.Replace What:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BAU").Range("A" & i).Value, _
                    replacement:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BAU").Range("B" & i).Value, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
                    Set Cell = Worksheets(fname).Range("A1:A" & lastrowsheet).FindNext(Cell)
                    
                End If
       Loop
  Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cell before entering the loop

```vb
 Set cell = rngSrc.Find(sA, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      After:=rngSrc.Cells(rngSrc.Cells.Count), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
        
 If Not cell Is Nothing Then
```

however you also need to avoid an endless loop by checking if the search has returned to the first one found.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsBAU As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, rngSrc As Range
    Dim fname As String, lastrow As Long, lastrowBAU As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, first As String
    Dim sA As String, sB As String
    
    fname = "Sheet1"
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets(fname)
        Set wsBAU = .Sheets("BAU")
    End With
    
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngSrc = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
    End With
    
    With wsBAU
        lastrowBAU = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
     With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngSrc = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
    End With
    
    ' search and replace
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To lastrowBAU
        sA = wsBAU.Cells(i, "A")
        sB = wsBAU.Cells(i, "B")
        
        Set cell = rngSrc.Find(sA, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      After:=rngSrc.Cells(rngSrc.Cells.Count), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
        
        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        
            first = cell.Address
            Do
                ' insert cell above
                cell.Insert xlDown
                cell.Offset(-1).Value2 = cell.Value2
                cell.Value2 = Replace(cell.Value2, sA, sB)
                ' expand search range
                n = n + 1
                Set rngSrc = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow + n)
                ' find next
                Set cell = rngSrc.FindNext(cell)
            Loop While cell.Address <> first
            
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " replacements", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```